# Microservice design - How call for every record

Tags: java, spring, rest, design-patterns, microservices

As I understood, in microservice design application every microservice serve exact purpose and have (must) own database.

But in case, when you show list of orders from Finance microservice and for every orders have customer which is on CRM microservice, its mean you must call getCustmerSimpeDetail for every order's row ?

Answer (score 0):

That's true, integration by database between microservices is one of example point of failure, so the best option is separate storage for each microservices. It does not mean that you can not duplicate data between databases, on the contrary you can. In this situation you can store base information about customers in the dabase for Finance microservice.

If you do not want duplicate data, you can create method getCustmersSimpeDetail with parameter as list of customers id. Which option is the best? It depends on concrete business scenarios.

Comment: I'm confused about using microservices or not. Not decided yet.

Comment: If it's new application, please read about the monolith first pattern. https://martinfowler.com/bliki/MonolithFirst.html